# Want to generate unique Ids as value changes from previous row using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to generate unique IDs as value changes from previous row in given column. I have dataframe in Spark Scala and want to add Unique_ID column to existing dataframe. I can not use Row Number over partitions or groupBy as same Product_IDs coming multiple times and want Unique_ID every time it is coming to column.

```
Product_IDs Unique_ID
Prod_1           1
Prod_1           1
Prod_1           1
Prod_2           2
Prod_3           3
Prod_3           3
Prod_2           4
Prod_3           5
Prod_1           6
Prod_1           6
Prod_4           7
```

I need this dataframe using Spark Scala.

Comment: First you'll have to explain how you define an ordering of row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution which isn't necessarily the most efficient (I admit I couldn't find a way to optimize it), and a bit long, but works.

I'm assuming the input is composed of records represented by this case class:

```
case class Record(id: Int, productId: String)
```

Where the `id` defines the **order**.

We'll perform two calculations:

1. For each record, find the **minimum** `id` of any *subsequent* record with a *different* `productId`
2. Group by that value (which represents a group of consecutive records with same `productId`, and then zipWithIndex to create the unique ID we're interested in

I'm mixing RDD operations (for #2) and SQL (for #1) mostly for convenience, I'm assuming both operations can be done in any API (although I didn't try):

```
val input = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  Record(1, "Prod_1"),
  Record(2, "Prod_1"),
  Record(3, "Prod_1"),
  Record(4, "Prod_2"),
  Record(5, "Prod_3"),
  Record(6, "Prod_3"),
  Record(7, "Prod_2"),
  Record(8, "Prod_3"),
  Record(9, "Prod_1"),
  Record(10, "Prod_1"),
  Record(11, "Prod_4")
))

input.registerTempTable("input")

// Step 1: find "nextShiftId" for each record
val withBlockId = sqlContext.sql(
  """
    |SELECT FIRST(a.id) AS id, FIRST(a.productId) AS productId, MIN(b.id) AS nextShiftId
    |FROM input a
    |LEFT JOIN input b ON a.productId != b.productId AND a.id < b.id
    |GROUP BY a.id
  """.stripMargin)

withBlockId.show()
// prints:
// +---+---------+-----------+
// | id|productId|nextShiftId|
// +---+---------+-----------+
// |  1|   Prod_1|          4|
// |  2|   Prod_1|          4|
// |  3|   Prod_1|          4|
// |  4|   Prod_2|          5|
// |  5|   Prod_3|          7|
// |  6|   Prod_3|          7|
// |  7|   Prod_2|          8|
// |  8|   Prod_3|          9|
// |  9|   Prod_1|         11|
// | 10|   Prod_1|         11|
// | 11|   Prod_4|       null|
// +---+---------+-----------+

// Step 2: group by "productId" and "nextShiftId"
val resultRdd = withBlockId.rdd
  .groupBy(r => (r.getAs[String]("productId"), r.getAs[Int]("nextShiftId")))
  // sort by nextShiftId to get the order right before adding index
  .sortBy {
     case ((prodId, 0), v) => Long.MaxValue // to handle the last batch where nextShiftId is null
     case ((prodId, nextShiftId), v) => nextShiftId
   }
  // zip with index (which would be the "unique id") and flatMap to just what we need:
  .values
  .zipWithIndex()
  .flatMap { case (records, index) => records.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("productId"), index+1))}

// transform back into DataFrame:
val result = sqlContext.createDataFrame(resultRdd)

result.show()
// prints:
// +------+---+
// |    _1| _2|
// +------+---+
// |Prod_1|  1|
// |Prod_1|  1|
// |Prod_1|  1|
// |Prod_2|  2|
// |Prod_3|  3|
// |Prod_3|  3|
// |Prod_2|  4|
// |Prod_3|  5|
// |Prod_1|  6|
// |Prod_1|  6|
// |Prod_4|  7|
// +------+---+
```

Comment: @ Tzach Zohar thank you very much, this is fantastic solution and worked very well for me.

Comment: can i do the same in pyspark

Answer (score 1):

There are tho ways to add a column with unique ids that I can think of just now. One is to use `zipWithUniqueId`:

```
val rows = df.rdd.zipWithUniqueId().map { 
    case (r: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ id)
} 

val newDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("uniqueIdColumn", LongType, false)))
```

another one is to use `MonotonicallyIncreasingId` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonicallyIncreasingId 
val newDf = df.withColumn("uniqueIdColumn", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

Comment: @Tzach Zohar 1st, thanks for your answers. Both of above function will give me just increasing sequence. But i want to generate Unique_ID number as product Ids changes from above row. for example for Prod_1, its unique_id is 1, Prod_2 its 2, Prod_3 its 3, again Prod_2 its increased by 1 as 4 and so on. so whenever product_id not equal to product ids in its above row then increase the Unique_Id by 1.

Comment: @Nikhil that's not my answer, I just edited it a bit for readability :)

Comment: @TzachZohar, do you have solution for this question?

Comment: If I had one I'd post it :)